# kable table not correctly displayed on github

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, kable

I am working on a color package for the company I work for. It contains a table to see the color of the company in an interactive way, with the actual color under the hex code (see picture below).
[image]

This works fine as long as I compile my rmd locally. However, when the file is compiled on Github, the underlying color disappears (see https://github.com/qwertzlbry/bsscol or picture below).

[image]

Does anyone know why Github is not displaying my table correctly?
The entire rmd file including all codes can be found at https://github.com/qwertzlbry/bsscol, any help on this topic is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the differences are due to two different renders. From what I can see, `kable_paper` outputs a *Markdown* text-document. When you are viewing it, something is rendering it into HTML, where the `<span>`-tag is allowed.

In the second screenshot, on GitHub, it is GitHub that is rendering the Markdown document into HTML. Alas, the [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://github.github.com/gfm/) does not support the `<span>` tag. So it simply ignores it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So is there any way around this `<span>` tag? I am not very experienced with html and the like.

Comment: Afraid not, other than including a literal image in the Markdown file.

Comment: I found a work arround using git hub pages. It does support the HTML  <span> tag.